# Disable filtering in kendo ui autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-autocomplete

How to disable filtering in kendo autocomplete UI? I am getting 5 records on search but only matching records are shown in autocomplete popup even though I haven't used filters.

```
scope.autocompleteOptions = {
        dataTextField: 'description',
        minLength:1,
        dataSource:{
          data: locationsData, 
          group:'provider',
          serverFiltering:false
        },
        template: kendo.template($('#roc-map-places-template').html())
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer this http://dojo.telerik.com/ikaYU

Comment: Thanks @SanyamiVaidya , But my question is about `kendo ui autocomplete`. I am unable to disable filtering in `kendo autocomplete`.

Comment: What filtering are you referring to?

Comment: I was not referring to server filtering here. I have already disabled it by doing `serverFiltering: false`. My concern was to disable all type of filtering. I have read in documentation that `filter: 'startswith'` is default filtering for `kendo autocomplete UI` and i have to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

I could clear filters in `kendo ui autocomplete` as follows :

```
var autocomplete=$('#autocomplete').data('kendoAutoComplete');
autocomplete.dataSource.filter([]);
```

This will just clear filters.

This would not disable filters but clears it.

Answer (score 0):

Late reply - but I just needed the same ability -

Solution: Use the "filtering" event
Example: see https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/autocomplete/events/filtering

```
<input id="autocomplete" />
<script>
$("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete({
  dataSource: [ "Apples", "Oranges" ],
  filtering: function(e) {
      var filter = e.filter;

      if (!filter.value) {
        //prevent filtering if the filter does not value
        e.preventDefault();
      }
  }
});
</script>
```